# What was William H. Clements' military service shown on this military grave registration?

Tags: palaeography, military-records, army, mississippi

I know that William H. Clements was part of the Mississippi Rifles from [a military pension record index entry](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:K8H4-BFX). Specifically, he served 1846-1847 in Company C.

[image: Record for William H Clements]

According to [the Army National Guard Special Designation Listing](http://www.history.army.mil/html/forcestruc/spdes-123-arng.html), "Mississippi Rifles" was a special designation for 155th Infantry Regiment, also known as "First Mississippi".

I found his [military grave registration](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33S7-9P33-GB3). I would like help transcribing the bottom of the page:

[image: military grave registration for William H. Clements]

I can read some of it:

```
Warren Co
11. Date Enlisted 1846         Date Discharged 1847
12. Service Army (Mex)         Rank Private
13. Company, outfit or ship Co C. 1st Miss Inf. " ------------ Southerners"
```

What is the missing word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the article [Mississippi and the U.S.-Mexican War, 1846-1848](http://mshistorynow.mdah.state.ms.us/articles/202/mississippi-and-the-us-mexican-war-1846-1848) by Sam Olden, posted on the website *Mississippi History Now* (an online publication of the Mississippi Historical Society), Company C was the **Vicksburg Southrons**.

See also this page at Tufts, which is a digital version of: [Colonel Charles E. Hooker, Confederate Military History, a library of Confederate States Military History](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2001.05.0264%3Achapter%3D2): Volume 12.2, Mississippi, Clement Anselm Evans, Ed.

> Vicksburg Southrons, Capt. D. N. Moody